# How to identify i.e. distinquish textual content from other serialized representations?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, text

Are there any algorithms that are could be used to distinguish or identify textual content from other serialized representations?

In my test case, I have at various locations of a file stored textual information such as (file-)names intermixed with other information such as serialized floating points. The textual content that I have has a leading [7-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) encoded length (similar to how [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET serializes strings). Ideally, I'd like to able to list all candidates that can be considered 'text'.

I have implemented a naive, rough and semi working algorithm. It goes like this: for every byte, decode a 7-bit encoded integer, evaluate if the content matches to human readable characters. However this approach gives a lot of false positives, duplicated entries. So my question is are there any algorithms that I could explore or alternatively how could I strengthen the conditions so that it matches the content I am looking for?.

```
bool read_string( char* buffer )
{
    unsigned char num3;
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    do
    {
        if (num2 == 0x23) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        //stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>( &num3), sizeof(num3));

        num3 = *buffer;
        num |= (num3 & 0x7f) << num2;
        num2 += 7;
        buffer++;
    }
    while ((num3 & 0x80) != 0);


    if( num > 0 && num < 2048 )
    {           
        bool is_false = false;
        for( int i = 0; i < num; ++i ) 
        {
            bool ischaracter = ( buffer[i] >= 'a' && buffer[i] <= 'z' ) || ( buffer[i] >= 'A' && buffer[i] <= 'Z' ) || ( buffer[i] >= '0' && buffer[i] <= '9' ) || ( buffer[i] == '/' || buffer[i] == '\\' || buffer[i] == '.' || buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '{' || buffer[i] == '}' || buffer[i] == ':'  || buffer[i] == '_' );
            if( ischaracter == false ) {
                is_false = true;
            }
        }

        if( !is_false )
        {
            std::string v;
            for( int i = 0; i < num; ++i ) 
                v.push_back( buffer[i] );
            printf("%s\r\n", v.c_str() );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever you come up with, ask yourself how you could break your solution with suitably crafted input, and how you would handle that.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the data, but your conditions look very strict already. I would check that the value is between 32 and 126, possibly also allowing tabs and new lines. Depending on the expected output, you could also require a minimum length for a string to be valid. As for the duplicates: Shouldn't you update `buffer` on successful reading, so that you can skip already recognised input in the calling function?